# threading loop isn`t kicking into action

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, while-loop, python-multithreading

I wrote this part of code, just to represent my problem and to learn how it works:

```
from threading import Thread
import time
done = 0
def loopA():
    while done  > 0:
        print "okay"
        time.sleep(2)
threadA = Thread(target = loopA)
threadA.start()
user = raw_input()
user = user.lower()
if user == "attempt":
    print "attempt detected"
    done = done + 1
```

What I expect it to do: The console should be asking for input, and as soon as I write `attempt` and hit return, it should start printing OKAY every 2 seconds. What am I missing?

Comment: errr `done = 0` so your `loopA` does nothing and returns immediately...

Comment: well yea, but it is the while loop, so I expect it to get updated and whenever the done changes value, it should start going. EDIT - the answer below this one solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Would this fix your problem?  The wait loop is inefficient, but it illustrates the concept.  Better yet would be to detect a KEYPRESS on "ENTER".

```
def loopA():
    while done == 0:
        pass
    while done > 0:
        print "okay"
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Yes, that made it. I guess some beginner ideas I am not familiar with yet. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just have a *race condition*: the thread starts, checks that the value is `0` and exits immediately, before the main program has a chance to increase the value.